# Has Dr. Connors ever experimented with mutant DNA instead of lizard?

Tags: marvel, x-men, spider-man

Dr. Connors is a scientist who is missing an arm. In various different forms of Spider-Man media, from the *Amazing Spider-Man* film to the comic books, he makes some kind of attempt to regrow his limbs using the DNA of a lizard, with disastrous results.

In *X3: The Last Stand*, a mutant is shown which can regrow limbs immediately after being cut-off. Wolverine cuts various limbs off only for them to grow back.

Given that Spider-Man and X-Men are both from the Marvel universe, has Dr. Connors ever experimented with mutants, such as the one above, in order to regrow his arm?

Comment: I believe the OP wants to ask whether Dr Connor is aware of the regenerating mutant or vice versa...

Comment: @ash_k29: yes, you are right.

Comment: Good question :) Now it's much more lucid..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first thing worth pointing out is that the mutant you saw in *X3: The Last Stand* and the Dr. Curt Connors from the original *Spider-Man* trilogy and the *The Amazing Spider-Man* films are not part of the same universe, thanks to the various rights issues between Sony Pictures (who own the live action rights to Spiderman and all related properties) and 20th Century Fox (who own the live action rights to X-Men and the Fantastic Four and all related properties (with some complex caveats)).

However, in the main Marvel Comics continuity and the Ultimate Universe, Spider-Man and the X-Men do indeed share the same world. As far as I am aware, a mutant with the specific power to quickly regrow limbs (such as the one see in *X3: The Last Stand*) has never been shown in the comics, but Wolverine himself has a healing factor that includes the ability to regrow limbs.

The problem here is that after his initial transformation into The Lizard, Dr. Curt Connors would re-transform into his bestial alter-ego frequently, with one trigger being stress or chemical reactions. Between his frequent retransformations into The Lizard, the ethical issues involved with experimentation on humans (and mutants), and the fact he has mainly only appeared in Spider-Man related comics, to the best of my knowledge, Dr. Curt Connors has never experimented on mutants.

Comment: Not to mention, getting a hold of one of those mutants is not exactly an easy task.

Comment: @Zibbobz You could just kidnap one. What could go wrong with kidnapping Wolverine?

Comment: @Zibbobz - Nah, these days Wolverine's DNA is available at Wal-Mart... I mean, Weapon CCCLXXXVII.

Comment: Maybe Stryker has started an online store for mutant dna... lol